# Multi carton shipping

Tags: checkout

Can Magento be configured to **ship multi cartons**?  As an example, If I want to ship `4 cartons` each weighing `5 pounds`, I need to feed to **FedEx** that the weight of the order is **20 lbs** but it is distributed over `4 cartons`.  Our developer is telling us that standard Magento will only use `1 carton` which will not give us the correct cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple shipments in Magento, see the user guide here:
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/order-processing/order-ship.html

The issue your dev might be having with FedEx is, that your order may be going in 1 'shipment' causing the above issue. Depending on the scale of your operation, it could be worth integrating into a warehouse management system, or developing a custom integration into your carriers API.